# c++ "error:passing 'const std::vector<int>' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]"

Tags: c++, class

I am trying to implement [this POMDP solver with given examples](https://github.com/AdaCompNUS/despot/blob/API_redesign/examples/cpp_models/navigation/src/navigation.cpp) for my decision making problem and I followed the documentation in the repository to build different relevant classes and functions in the header file

```
class SimpleState: public State {
public:
        int position; 
        int context;
        int time;

        SimpleState();
        SimpleState(int _position, int _context, int _time) :
        rat_position(_position),
        context(_context),
        time(_time) {
        }
        SimpleState(int _state_id);
        ~SimpleState();

        std::string text() const;
};
    SimpleState::SimpleState() {
    }

class StarMazeProblem : public DSPOMDP,
     public MDP {
protected:
        std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<State> > > transition_probabilities_; //state, action, [state, weight]

        mutable MemoryPool<SimpleState> memory_pool_;

        std::vector<SimpleState*> states_;

        mutable std::vector<ValuedAction> mdp_policy_;

public:
        enum {CENTER = 0, RIGHT = 1, LEFT = 2};
        
public:
      StarMazeProblem();
      int NumStates() const;
      void ComputeDefaultActions(std::string type)  const;
      ParticleUpperBound* CreateParticleUpperBound(std::string name = "DEFAULT") const;//?
      ScenarioUpperBound* CreateScenarioUpperBound(std::string name = "DEFAULT",
              std::string particle_bound_name = "DEFAULT") const;

      ScenarioLowerBound* CreateScenarioLowerBound(std::string name = "DEFAULT",
              std::string particle_bound_name = "DEFAULT") const;
}
```

and in the `starmaze.cpp` file the relevant lines are

```
int StarMazeProblem::NumStates() const {
     return CONTEXT * POSITIONS * TIME;
}
void StarMazeProblem::ComputeDefaultActions(string type) const {
    cerr << "Default action = " << type << endl;
    if (type == "MDP") {
        const_cast<StarMazeProblem*>(this)->ComputeOptimalPolicyUsingVI();
        int num_states = NumStates();
        default_action_.resize(num_states);

        double value = 0;
        for (int s = 0; s < num_states; s++) {
            default_action_[s] = policy_[s].action;
            value += policy_[s].value;
        }
    } else {
        cerr << "Unsupported default action type " << type << endl;
        exit(0);
    }
}
ScenarioLowerBound* StarMazeProblem::CreateScenarioLowerBound(string name,
                                     string particle_bound_name="DEFAULT") const {
        const DSPOMDP* model = this;
        const StateIndexer* indexer = this;
        const StatePolicy* policy = this;                                 
        ScenarioLowerBound* bound = NULL;
        if (name == "TRIVIAL" ) {
            bound = new TrivialParticleLowerBound(this);
        } else if (name == "RANDOM") {
            bound = new RandomPolicy(this,
                          CreateParticleLowerBound(particle_bound_name));
        } else if (name == "MODE" || name == "DEFAULT") {
            ComputeDefaultActions("MDP");
             bound = new ModeStatePolicy(model, *indexer, *policy,
                          CreateParticleLowerBound(particle_bound_name));                             
        }  else {
            cerr << "Unsupported scenario lower bound: " << name << endl;
            exit(1);
        }
        return bound;
}
```

here I got the following error for the above code:

```
src/starmaze.cpp:301:36: error: passing 'const std::vector<int>' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
   default_action_.resize(num_states);
                                    ^
In file included from /opt/local/include/gcc7/c++/vector:64:0,
                 from ../../../include/despot/interface/lower_bound.h:4,
                 from ../../../include/despot/core/builtin_lower_bounds.h:4,
                 from src/starmaze.h:3,
                 from src/starmaze.cpp:1:
/opt/local/include/gcc7/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:689:7: note:   in call to 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::resize(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _Tp = int; _Alloc = std::allocator<int>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]'
       resize(size_type __new_size)
       ^~~~~~
```

I have basic c++ knowledge and I could not figure out the reason for the error since I followed the examples. Any suggestion?

Comment: The most important part is here: `no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const despot::StarMazeProblem*' to 'const despot::MDP*'`. Did you mean to inherit `StarMazeProblem` from `MDP`?

Comment: Apply what you just learned: `no known conversion for argument 2 from 'const despot::StarMazeProblem' to 'const despot::StateIndexer&'`. Did you mean to inherit from StateIndexer?

Answer (score 5):

### Important to know before reading

I've looked over this code several times, and cannot find where `default_action_` is declared as a `const std::vector<int>`. This leads me to assume (*based on the fact that the compiler recognizes it as such*) that the variable is declared in one of the parent classes: `public DSPOMDP, public MDP`.

### You are trying to modify a `const vector<int>`

This issue is pretty straight-forward.
You cannot change a `const std::vector<Ty>`
The whole point of making something *const* is to prevent the programmer from changing it.
Whatever you are trying to do here, you should consider copying the vector data into a new vector, and make the changes to it in the copy.

> Okay so let's say you decided to do the naughty deed and remove const from the *.h file wherever it may be. You'll still have an issue (*see below*)

### You are trying to modify the class instance from a *const* method

**This is if you removed *const* from the vector**

The `default_action_.resize(num_states);` is going to cause the compiler to yell at you.
The issue here is now your method `StarMazeProblem::ComputeDefaultActions()` is specified as *const*. This means you **cannot** change your class instance in any way from within that function/class method. What you are doing is modifying the *default_action_* vector by calling `resize()` on it. This inevitably **changes** the class instance which is forbidden because your method is declared *const* and your *default_action_* vector is declared somewhere in your class hierarchy. Additionally you are changing the vector directly by assigning it to an rvalue (*See code below*)

```
int num_states = NumStates();
default_action_.resize(num_states); // <---- default_action_ cannot be modified

for (int s = 0; s < num_states; s++) {
    default_action_[s] = policy_[s].action; // <---- default_action_ cannot be modified
    value += policy_[s].value;
}
```

## Solution

You need a copy of the vector you are trying to modify. Going into *h* files and changing them without knowing 100% exactly what you are doing is never the answer.
Making a temporary vector in the class method, copying the data to it, and manipulating the copy is completely allowed and will not give you any compiler errors; however, this approach may completely avoid your official goal. It looks like you are *really trying* to change the *default_action_* vector and that almost seems like your true goal here.

It's hard for me to give you a definitive answer on this specific topic. Mainly because I do not know what this entire class hierarchy does or what it is for exactly (*I briefly looked over the code in the link provided*.)

What you'll need to do ultimately is determine why you are trying to change that vector, and why it was made *const* by the original developers. Then you can determine if there is a better way other than explicitly removing the *constness* of the vector.

**If you are still trying to make changes to the class instance read below**

This solution part has to do with the qualifier of the class you are dealing with.

You can either *remove* the constant qualifier from the class method if it is absolutely necessary to make changes to the class instance from within that method.

OR

Find an alternative method for what you are trying to do, and break it up into multiple method calls on the class instance.

Comment: `default_action_` doesn't need to be declared `const`. It's used in `const` context since the member function is `const` qualified, so all (non-`mutable`) members are viewed as `const` as you yourself concluded. `ComputeDefaultActions()` doesn't return anything. It is designed to change the internal state of the object so rather than assuming that `default_action_` is declared `const` I would assume that making `ComputeDefaultActions()` `const`-qualified is where OP made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You've made `ComputeDefaultActions()` `const`-qualified, but there is very little that says that it should be.

- It calls `ComputeOptimalPolicyUsingVI()` which is not `const`-qualified since it changes the internal state of `*this`. You've worked around that by casting away `const` on `this` - but that function `resize`s `policy_` to also be `NumStates()` big which `ComputeDefaultActions()` depends on - otherwise the internal loop would be very dangerous.
- It changes `default_action_` by `resize`ing it and by assigning its elements. This *may* be a mistake, if the computation made is actually meant to not change `*this` but ... (see next bullet)
- It doesn't return anything. Everything the function does is to change the internal state of `*this`. The computed `value` is just dropped at the end of the calculation and it's not even used internally in the function. Either make the function `return value` or remove `value` completely.

Suggested changes:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>

void StarMazeProblem::ComputeDefaultActions(string type) { // non-const
    cerr << "Default action = " << type << endl;
    if (type == "MDP") {
        ComputeOptimalPolicyUsingVI(); // no casting needed

        default_action_.resize(policy_.size()); // dependency made clear

        // Use the standard transform function:
        std::transform(policy_.begin(), policy_.end(), default_action_.begin(),
                       [](const auto& p) { return p.action; });
    } else {
        // friendlier than exit():
        throw std::runtime_error("Unsupported default action type " + type);
    }
}
```